# C# not creating the excel file and cannot write in different excel sheets

Tags: c#, excel

First of all in my code im opening an excel sheet and reading it into a list. Second of all im closing this excel sheet and creating a new excel sheet:

```
excel_init("C:\\Users\\oma\\Desktop\\excel2.xlsx"); // this path does NOT exist yet
```

Next its going to this method:

```
static void excel_init(String path)
{
    appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        // then go and load this into excel
        newWorkbook_First = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, true, true);
        objsheet = (_Worksheet)appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            appExcel.Visible = true;
            newWorkbook_First = appExcel.Workbooks.Add(1);
            objsheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)newWorkbook_First.Sheets[1];
            objsheet.Name = ("test");
            var newSheet3 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)appExcel.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, appExcel.Worksheets[appExcel.Worksheets.Count], 1, XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            newSheet3.Name = "test2";
            var newSheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)appExcel.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, appExcel.Worksheets[appExcel.Worksheets.Count], 1, XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            newSheet2.Name = "test3";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It wont create excel2.xlsx on my desktop, why not?

Next in my main I am shouting excel_setValue this way:

```
excel_setValue("C", "hello", "");
```

This is the excel_setValue function:

```
static void excel_setValue(string cellname, string value, string color)
{
    objsheet.get_Range(cellname).set_Value(Type.Missing, value);
    if (kleur == "red")
    {
        objsheet.get_Range(cellname).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    }
}
```

How do I add the sheet to this? For exmaple: excel_setValue(cellname, value, color, sheetname)

Finally I do excel_close();

the excel_close function:

```
static void excel_close()
        {
            if (appExcel != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    newWorkbook_First.Close();
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet);
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel.ActiveWorkbook);
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel);
                    appExcel = null;
                    objsheet = null;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    appExcel = null;
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
        }
```

It closes and ask me if I wanna save/not-save or cancel it. And it will save @ documents with no errors given

Comment: `"It wont create excel2.xlsx on my desktop, why not?"` - In what way does it fail?  Is there an error?  Is it creating the file somewhere else?  Please include more details.

Comment: no errors were given, it closes and tells me if I want to save the file in documents, not save the file or just cancel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create my Excel like this worked fine for me!

You need to do the folowing in you code before the `newWorkbook_First.close();` part:

```
 newWorkbook_First.SaveAs(totalPath);
```

I hope this will help you solve the problems..

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


internal static bool ExportDGV(DataGridView DGV, List<string> selectedCustomerList, string path, string fileName, string exportName, int exportType, string mailSubject)
{
    string totalPath;
    //Create an Excel application instance
    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
    excelApp.Visible = false;
    worksheet = excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;

    //set headers
    for (int i = 1; i < DataGridView.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
    {
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = DGV.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
    }
    createList(worksheet, DGV);

    //Create excel with the choosen name
    Worksheet sheet1 = excelWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
    worksheet.Name = fileName;

    totalPath = path + "/" + fileName + ".xlsx";

    //if path exist add a number
    totalPath = directoryExist(totalPath, path, fileName);
    //Save exel and Quit exelApp 

    excelWorkBook.SaveAs(totalPath);
    excelWorkBook.Close();
    excelApp.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EpPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library for excel. It is very easy to use and well documented. You don't need to use COM classes anymore

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, rather than an answer.